# Execute SnowFlake procedure with Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, procedure

I write you because I don´t know how to execute a snowFlake procedure with Azure Databricks.

This is my SnowFlake procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getBalanceFrontAndInTotalFront(tableName VARCHAR, stringBalanceFront VARCHAR, stringInTotalFront VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
NOT NULL
LANGUAGE javascript
AS

$$

var tableName = TABLENAME;
var balanceFront = STRINGBALANCEFRONT;
var inTotalFront = STRINGINTOTALFRONT;

// Dynamically compose the SQL statement to execute.
var sqlCommand = "SELECT BALANCE_FRONT, IN_TOTAL_FRONT, SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT FROM (SELECT " + balanceFront + " AS \"BALANCE_FRONT\", AMOUNT, " + inTotalFront + " AS \"IN_TOTAL_FRONT\" FROM " + tableName + ") GROUP BY  BALANCE_FRONT, IN_TOTAL_FRONT";

// Prepare statement.
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sqlCommand});

// Execute Statement
var rs = stmt.execute();
  
arrayValues=[]
 
while (rs.next()) {
    var column1 = rs.getColumnValue(1);
    var column2 = rs.getColumnValue(2);
    var column3 = rs.getColumnValue(3);
    arrayValues.push([column1 + ':' + column3 + ':' + column2]);
}
return arrayValues;

$$;
```

When I execute the procedure in SnowFlake

```
set stringBalanceFront = 'CASE WHEN Balance_Type like (\'%A%\')THEN \'ACTIVO\' WHEN Balance_Type like (\'%P%\') THEN \'PASIVO\' WHEN Balance_Type like (\'%N%\') THEN \'NETO\' ELSE \'RESTO\' END';
set stringInTotalFront = 'CASE WHEN Balance_Type like (\'%A%\')THEN \'true\' ELSE \'false\' END';

CALL getBalanceFrontAndInTotalFront('DMAAS_OUTPUT_DATA_TABLE_0049_D18CER', $stringBalanceFront, $stringInTotalFront);
```

I obtain next array of strings
RESTO:-184281744:false,ACTIVO:-17881395:true,NETO:20599:false,PASIVO:12672:false

I am trying to run this procedure from Spark with the following code and it obviously fails

```
val stringBalanceFront = Funciones.generarCondiciones(dfOrdenado, Variables.CAMPO_BALANCE_FRONT.toLowerCase())
val stringInTotalFront = Funciones.generarCondiciones(dfOrdenado, Variables.CAMPO_IN_TOTAL_FRONT.toLowerCase())

val query = s"CALL getBalanceFrontAndInTotalFront(${cfgVal.getRutaMasterNoAgregada}, ${stringBalanceFront}, ${stringInTotalFront});"

val arrayBalanceFront = spark.read
  .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
  .options(snowOptionsRead)
  .option("query", query)
  .load()
```

And I get the next error:

> 21/07/15 17:14:36 ERROR Uncaught throwable from user code: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
> syntax error line 1 at position 15 unexpected 'CALL'.

What is the correct way to execute a SnowFlake procedure from Spark? Keep in mind that I want to return the results to a val in Spark.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards.

Comment: The limitation seems to be coming from Spark, see this [**issue**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32014) opened with Apache.

Comment: If you have access to the Query History window or the view "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY", or can have an admin look, you can see how the statement arrived in Snowflake. There may be a possibility to address it with that information. If not, at least it will confirm whether or not there's a fix or workaround.

Comment: Hello Greg, thanks for your answer. As you say, I can see the Query History, however the problem is that I need a way to execute a stored procedure into SnowFlake and it cannot be possible with this sentece: val arrayBalanceFront = spark.read
  .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
  .options(snowOptionsRead)
  .option("query", query)
  .load()